# Entering supervisor mode in PhoenixBIOS

Tags: boot, bios

I'm trying to change the boot order on a VM that uses PhoenixBIOS. I can get to the setup utility. However, I can't figure out how to get into supervisor mode, which is required to change the boot order.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? My Google-fu fails me.

Comment: What's your VM environment? VMWare Server, ESX, ...?

Comment: VMWare Workstation. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by accident: (a) Unset BIOS password; (b) rebooted and pressed F4 for network boot, which failed of course; (c) rebooted and pressed F2 and I was supervisor. No logic there.... but worked.